# Sort GridView by column name

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview

I am making a `GridView` and assigning it to the `View` property of a ListView. The `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<Entry>`. `Entry` is a model in my MVVM application, and it contains a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`. It also has an indexer which fetches the first `KeyValurPair<string,string>`'s `Value` property (from the list) which matches the indexer parameter. So it's much like a dictionary.

Now here's how I am making the GridView.

```
foreach (Column column in category.Columns.Where(c => c.IsVisibleInTable)) {
    var gridViewColumn = new GridViewColumn {
                                                Header = column.Name,
                                                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding($"[{column.Name}].Value")
                                            };
    gridView.Columns.Add(gridViewColumn);
}
```

`Column` is also a model but that's not really relevant here.

Now I want to tell the GridView to sort based on the first column. But I can't use the DefaultView of the `ItemsSource` and add a `SortDescription` to it because `SortDescription` expects a Property name whereas I am not binding to a property name but instead to an indexer.
So how can I sort based on the second column?

Comment: Order before to add values in the gridview is a valid solution for you?

Comment: Maybe. But everytime I add a new entry or edit an entry or delete, I will have to order it. If there's a built-in way, I prefer that

Comment: If you try to order a column in your grid and then edit a value, 
for what I remember, `GridView` doesn't perform an automatic reorder of the records. You can use an `ObservableCollection` to bind your `GridView`. In this way you can reorder `ObservableCollection` and the `GridView` will be sort too.

Comment: Good solution. But I don't want to mess with my models. It must be the view and view only because ordering has nothing to do with models.

Comment: You don't need to change your model but only your "controller". You can build your grid as you bind your ListView. It's that right?

Comment: But what do you mean by controller?

Comment: The class behinde your xaml file

Comment: @erikscandola, I don't quite understand you. I would appreciate if you provide some example :)

Comment: Ok. You work with wpf right? Ok. You have a model (simple and clean class with properties), a view (the xaml file with your grid) and a cs file behinde the xaml file (where you have the initialization of your window). I assume that your foreach is in this class. So, in this class build your grid as you bind your listview. Use the class for logic and no the model. I hope I made it clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

here is sorting algo

iN gridview pass this two parameter aspx
`AllowSorting="true"
  OnSorting="OnSorting"`

`private string SortDirection
        {
            get { return ViewState["SortDirection"] != null ? ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString() : "ASC"; }
            set { ViewState["SortDirection"] = value; }
        }
        protected void OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BindGrid(e.SortExpression);
        }`

here we have to place the code
`  private void BindGrid(string sortExpression = null)
        {
            conn.Open();

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from [test].[dbo].[myform] order by name", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (sortExpression != null)
            {
                DataView dv = dt.AsDataView();
                this.SortDirection = this.SortDirection == "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";
                dv.Sort = sortExpression + " " + this.SortDirection;
                GridView2.DataSource = dv;
            }
            else
            {
                GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            }
            GridView2.DataBind();
            conn.Close();

        }

    }`
```